# How to dynamically extend PickCanvas object for MouseListener click event in a Java Applet (using Java3D)?

Tags: java, applet, java-3d, mouselistener, canvas3d

I am developing a Java applet using `Java3D`. It starts up with a `BranchGroup` object (containing a set of points) which is added to a Locale object. A `PickCanvas` is created starting from the Locale and a class implementing `MouseListener` is constructed starting from said `PickCanvas`.

Mouse clicks are being detected correctly at this stage. The issue I am having is that whenever I start adding more points to my applet (by creating a new `BranchGroup` object for each set of points that is loaded and then appending this object to my initial `Locale` object) mouse clicks are not being registered when newly added points are selected.

I probably do something wrong when I refresh the `PickCanvas` of my `MouseListener` implementing object after adding new `BranchGroup` objs. How can I make it so that points that are added in branchgroups after startup are picked by mouse clicks?

Here's how the locale, the first branchgroup and mouselistener are created:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
GraphicsConfiguration gc = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(gc);
Utm_Coord_3d observerPoint = new Utm_Coord_3d();
BranchGroup scene=loadPoints(geoPathID, startSequenceID, endSequenceID, observerPoint);
Locale mLocale = new Locale(simpleU);
mLocale.addBranchGraph(scene);
PickCanvas pickCanvas = new PickCanvas(canvas3D, mLocale);
pickCanvas.setMode(PickCanvas.BOUNDS);
MouseMethodsPoints myMouseEventListener = new MouseMethodsPoints(simpleU, viewT3D, pickCanvas);
canvas3D.addMouseListener(myMouseEventListener);
canvas3D.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseEventListener);
canvas3D.addMouseWheelListener(myMouseEventListener);
KeyMethodsPoints myKeyEventListener = new KeyMethodsPoints(canvas3D, simpleU, viewT3D, geoPathID, startSequenceID, endSequenceID, tiltX, scene,mLocale, myMouseEventListener);
canvas3D.addKeyListener(myKeyEventListener);
canvas3D.requestFocus();
```

And finally this is how I add branchgroups to the locale object updating the pickcanvas:

```
BranchGroup newBranchGroup=MainPoints.loadPoints(geoPathID, upperBound+1, upperBound+nFilesLoaded, null);
newBranchGroup.compile();
mLocale.addBranchGraph(newBranchGroup);         
PickCanvas pickCanvas = new PickCanvas(canvas3D,mLocale);       
pickCanvas.setMode(PickCanvas.BOUNDS);
mMouseMethodsPoints.setPickCanvas(pickCanvas);
```

Where `setPickCanvas()` sets pickCanvas in the `MouseListener` implementing class object.
I even tried creating a new MouseMethodsPoints object every time I add a branchgroup but clicks would still find no points in the areas of the new branchgroups.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I edited my answer to make what I wanted to know more clear and even added a question mark for your pleasure even if I think my request was pretty clear.

Comment: There's no accounting for what people think.  Note that sometimes helpers will do a find on '?' & if the first hit is *"Know someone who can answer?"* they move to the next post that might not only have a question, but also a question mark.  My advice is: add one for your *own* benefit.